# Best way to edit long text in a QTableWidget cell?

Tags: pyqt5

**What I want to achieve**: an easier way to edit longer text (one or two paragraphs) in a `QTableWidget` cell.

**The problem:** `resizeRows` wraps the text in the cell when the table is displayed. However, if I try to edit the cell, all the text appears on one line which makes it awkward to edit.

**What I've tried**: I tried implementing a `QTextEdi`t widget for editing:

```
class EditDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
            textedit = QTextEdit(parent)
            textedit.setPlainText(editor.text())
        return textedit
```

That fixed the editing problem, although I have to rely on the edit box losing focus to save the text. However, after editing, the default `QTableWidgetItem` now shows HTML in the edited cell. I had thought that using `setPlainText()` would prevent this. The only text entered was "THE NOTE TEXT", seen in the middle of this screenshot:

[image: After using QTextEdit to edit cell]

If I then try to edit the cell again, the HTML is stripped out and just the original text ("THE NOTE TEXT") remains in the `QTextEdit` box until again I exit the editor.

Questions:

1. Is my approach a good way to implement multiline editing in a
   `QTableWidget`?
2. If so, how can I get rid of the HTML markup that the
   `QTableWidgetItem` is now displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need a multiple line editor and no formatting (colors, text style, etc.) then use QPlainTextEdit.

The reason behind the returned HTML is that the *default property* (see the [USER attribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html)) of QTextEdit is [`html`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop): item delegates use the `USER` property as default to set the value of the editor and then set it back on the model, meaning that [`setEditorData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setEditorData) will behave like using `setHtml()` and [`setModelData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setModelData) like `toHtml()`.

The user property for QPlainTextEdit is just [`plainText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#plainText-prop), so there will be no conversion in either case.

Also note that your implementation of `createEditor()` will potentially raise an exception if the default editor is not a QLineEdit (if the data uses numbers or Qt dates/times), since `textexit` is only declared in the `if`, but that's a bad way to do so anyway (you're creating a widget that won't be used).
Besides, calling `textedit.setPlainText(editor.text())` is useless, because at that point the editor is still empty and it will be filled only by `setEditorData()` (which would overwrite its contents anyway).

A more correct approach would check the data type and return the editor accordingly, then let the delegate fill the widget in its own.

```py
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if isinstance(index.data(), str):
            return QTextEdit(parent)
        return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
```

Finally, be aware that many have tried to implement multiple line editors in item views, and very few attempts actually achieve a *valid* result. Many issues are related with the available item geometry, cursor navigation, UX aspects and focus management, and almost any solution has to accept some level of compromise that many users might find annoying. The most common acceptable (and less "hated") solution is to use an *external* editor, either shown in another part of the UI or through a dialog window.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I need to read up more on PyQt - any recommendations for really getting to grips with it?

Comment: @backseat there are some books, but it also depends on what you want/need to do. The first and most important source is, obviously, the documentation: experimenting with classes and frameworks is essential to understand how things work, while studying what they can do and how. Btw, remember that if an answer solves your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left (that's not the same as upvoting).